# PHP create date from format method not working as expected

Tags: php, datetime

The following returns `false`:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("Ymd-Gi", '20170629-902')
```

I've gone over the formats in http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, and it all seems to be correct.

Any idea why?

Comment: It looks like a PHP bug. It successfully parses `0902` using both `Hi` and `Gi` format specifiers but it fails to parse `902` as `09:02` using the `Gi` format specifier, as it is documented. No version from 5.4 to 7.1 parses it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty to take a look at the php source and found the function responsible for parsing the `format` string: [timelib_get_nr_ex](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0ba04f77379b5d277f5bd190c1542a0d91289978/ext/date/lib/parse_date.re#L465-L491). it looks  like this,

```
static timelib_sll timelib_get_nr_ex(char **ptr, int max_length, int *scanned_length)
{
    char *begin, *end, *str;
    timelib_sll tmp_nr = TIMELIB_UNSET;
    int len = 0;

    while ((**ptr < '0') || (**ptr > '9')) {
        if (**ptr == '\0') {
            return TIMELIB_UNSET;
        }
        ++*ptr;
    }
    begin = *ptr;
    while ((**ptr >= '0') && (**ptr <= '9') && len < max_length) {
        ++*ptr;
        ++len;
    }
    end = *ptr;
    if (scanned_length) {
        *scanned_length = end - begin;
    }
    str = timelib_calloc(1, end - begin + 1);
    memcpy(str, begin, end - begin);
    tmp_nr = strtoll(str, NULL, 10);
    timelib_free(str);
    return tmp_nr;
}
```

And [this is how](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0ba04f77379b5d277f5bd190c1542a0d91289978/ext/date/lib/parse_date.re#L2008-L2014) it's been called when there's a 'G' or 'H' found in the format string.

```
// ...
case 'G': /* two digit hour, with leading zero */
case 'H': /* two digit hour, without leading zero */
        TIMELIB_CHECK_NUMBER;
        if ((s->time->h = timelib_get_nr((char **) &ptr, 2)) == TIMELIB_UNSET) {
                add_pbf_error(s, "A two digit hour could not be found", string, begin);
        }
        break;
// ...
```

As you can see, `timelib_get_nr_ex` function doesn't check for a leading zero. however, it still consumes two digits. so in your case, the hour portion becomes `90`. and then there's only one digit remaining for the minute part. but according to the format `i`, it should be a two digit value (including leading zeros). so this throws an error: *"A two digit minute could not be found"*

To check for any errors/warning, you can use this,

```
DateTime::getLastErrors()
```

Also for the 12 hour format they have a validation like this.

```
if (s->time->h > 12) {
    add_pbf_error(s, "Hour can not be higher than 12", string, begin);
}
```

There's nothing similar if you use 'G' or 'H'. so it doesn't log an error when it incorrectly parses it as `90`.

***It looks like you gonna have to use a zero when there's only one digit, regardless of the format value you used.***

Answer (score 0):

I think `G` should be with leading zero. then `0902` instead of `902`

Comment: But it says in the docs that it can be without a leading 0: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: [`H` is with leading `0`. `G` is without it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) but apparently it works only on formatting a date and not also on parsing one.

Comment: @Nav, yes it is something like a bug or document problem.